# How to get attribute, value and text from tags in array using phpquery

Tags: php, html, phpquery

I'm trying to get value, text and hyperlinks using PHPQuery from a large file and convert it to Array.
I have tried some of the code but confusion in `foreach` loop to get data from all `class="hl"` into an array.

```
<?php 
$str ='
<main>
<div class="artfeed ">
<div class="split split_0">
 <div class="split_in">

  <div class="hl" data-id="1036294107">
    <span class="f" country="US"><!-- --></span>
    <div class="hl__inner"><a class="hll" href="http://example.com/001/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Some of text here</a>
     <span class="end"></span> 
     <span class="meta">
      <span class="src" data-pub="DATAPUB">
      <span class="src-part">
      exampleOne.com
      <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-cog fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="cog" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
      </span>
      </span>
      <span class="time" data-time="1592802284">12:04</span>
      </span>
     <a class="hl__menu-toggle c-context-menu__btn js-article-menu__toggle" href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="hl" data-id="1036294107">
    <span class="f" country="US"><!-- --></span>
    <div class="hl__inner"><a class="hll" href="http://example.com/001/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Some of text here</a>
     <span class="end"></span> 
     <span class="meta">
      <span class="src" data-pub="DATAPUB">
      <span class="src-part">
      exampleOne.com
      <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-cog fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="cog" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
      </span>
      </span>
      <span class="time" data-time="1592802284">12:04</span>
      </span>
     <a class="hl__menu-toggle c-context-menu__btn js-article-menu__toggle" href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="hl" data-id="1036294107">
    <span class="f" country="US"><!-- --></span>
    <div class="hl__inner"><a class="hll" href="http://example.com/001/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Some of text here</a>
     <span class="end"></span> 
     <span class="meta">
      <span class="src" data-pub="DATAPUB">
      <span class="src-part">
      exampleOne.com
      <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-cog fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="cog" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
      </span>
      </span>
      <span class="time" data-time="1592802284">12:04</span>
      </span>
     <a class="hl__menu-toggle c-context-menu__btn js-article-menu__toggle" href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
';
?>
```

Need result like this:

```
/*
Array()
Need result: 
Country  : US
href     : http://example.com/001/
Text     : Some of text here
src-part : exampleOne.com
time     : 12:04

Country  : US
href     : http://example.com/001/
Text     : Some of text here
src-part : exampleOne.com
time     : 12:04

Country  : US
href     : http://example.com/001/
Text     : Some of text here
src-part : exampleOne.com
time     : 12:04
*/
```

I have some of code

```
<?php
require("phpQuery.php");
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($str);
$doc =  $doc['body']->find('main')->find('.artfeed')->find('.hl');
$links = array();
foreach($doc['div'] as $item)
{
 $node = pq($item);
  $sibling = $node->next();
  if ( $sibling->is('a:first') ) {
      $links[] = array(
      $node->attr('country'),
      $sibling->attr('href'),
      $sibling->text(),
    ); 
  } 
}

// Display result:
print_r($links);
?>
```

Comment: What's the current output of $links? One thing that I immediately noticed is that country is set on the span, not the div, so I don't think getting the attr like this will work.

Comment: The current output is empty array and Can we mention class="hl" class in foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you `print_r($doc)` after the following line, are you seeing what you'd expect to see as far as the document structure?

```
$doc =  $doc['body']->find('main')->find('.artfeed')->find('.hl');
```

I've used Simple HTML Dom before but not phpQuery so I'm not sure if there is an error in the above line or somewhere else.

Based on examples I saw though, you should be able to use CSS syntax to find elements. Change your doc to something like this:

```
$doc =  $doc['body']->find('main')->find('.artfeed');
```

Then just use pq() and find() with CSS syntax to find your elements directly without the loop.

```
$content = pq($doc);
$links[] = array(
    $content->find('div.hl > span.f')->attr('country'),
    $content->find('div.hl > div.hl__inner > a.hll')->attr('href'),
    $content->find('div.hl > div.hl__inner > a.hll')->text(),
);
```

EDIT: For multiple hl divs, I think something like this might work:

```
$doc =  $doc['body']->find('main')->find('.artfeed');
foreach (pq($doc)->find('.hl') as $hl) {
    $links[] = array(
        $hl->find('span.f')->attr('country'),
        $hl->find('div.hl__inner > a.hll')->attr('href'),
        $hl->find('div.hl__inner > a.hll')->text(),
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for you valuable answer. But actually i need it in foreach loop because i have more  data `class="hl"` can you help me further more.

Comment: I don't follow what more data means with regard to the h1 class. Is all the data that you need inside `class="h1"` or at there more `h` class elements? Does the above code work to get the three values listed there? Please clarify what purpose the loop serves and provide as much info as possible. I'll take another look at this in the morning.

Comment: Yes the above code working fine thank you. I have changed the question please check it and i mean i have multi `class="hl"` and i want get the record from all `class="hl"` and put into array.

Comment: I modified the answer based on having multiple `hl` classes. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Not working!
Error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Comment: `$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($str); 
$doc =  $doc['body']->find('main')->find('.newsfeed:first');
/* echo pq($doc)->find('.hl'); die(); // worked */
$i =0;
foreach (pq($doc)->find('.hl') as $hl) {
        echo $hl . $i;
      $i++;  
}`

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: Use `print_r()` instead of `echo`. The error is telling you the element is not a string, so I don't think `echo $hl` will work. Try `print_r($hl)`.